# Python - trouble with nested variables in XML using minidom

Tags: python, xml, parsing, minidom

I'm using Python (minidom) to parse an XML file and print the output like a csv file:

```
0.0,0.0,51.3,46.6,
49.9,49.0,51.0,46.6,
36.0,24.0,47.8,42.2,
51.0,46.6,49.3,34.1,
```

Instead, the program produces the following, skipping the 'Q' tags unless they are the last tag in their respective 'Event' tags... Why is my program failing to print these?

```
0.0,0.0,,46.6
49.9,49.0,,
36.0,24.0,42.2,
51.0,46.6,,
```

Here is the XML source file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Games id = "1">
  <Game id="1" competition_id="1">
    <Event id="0" x="0.0" y="0.0">
      <Q id="a" end_x="51.3" />
      <Q id="b" end_y="46.6" />
    </Event>
    <Event id="1" x="49.9" y="49.0">
      <Q id="a" end_x="51.0" />
      <Q id="b" end_y="46.6" />
      <Q id="c" q1="tap" />
    </Event>
    <Event id="2" x="0.0" y="0.0">
      <Q id="a" end_y="47.8" />
      <Q id="b" end_x="42.2" />
    </Event>
    <Event id="3" x="51.0" y="46.6">
      <Q id="a" end_y="49.3" />
      <Q id="b" end_x="34.1" />
      <Q id="c" q1="17.8" />
    </Event>
</Game>
```

And here is my code:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import xml.dom.minidom

DOMTree = parse('myfile.xml');
collection = DOMTree.documentElement;

# Get all events in the collection
events = collection.getElementsByTagName("Event")

# Iterate through events
for event in events:
    start_x = event.getAttribute('x');
    start_y = event.getAttribute('y');

    qualifiers = event.getElementsByTagName('Q');

    # Iterate through qualifiers

    for qualifier in qualifiers:
        end_x= qualifier.getAttribute('end_x');
        end_y= qualifier.getAttribute('end_y');

    print start_x + ',' + start_y + ',' + end_x + ',' + end_y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the structure of your for qualifier in qualifiers loop, nothing happens to the end_x and end_y within the loop. That means that the code runs and reassigns the value for end_x and end_y. At the end of the loop, end_x and end_y are the values of the last qualifiers

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import xml.dom.minidom

DOMTree = parse('myfile.xml');
collection = DOMTree.documentElement;

# Get all events in the collection
events = collection.getElementsByTagName("Event")

# Iterate through events
for event in events:
    start_x = event.getAttribute('x');
    start_y = event.getAttribute('y');

    qualifiers = event.getElementsByTagName('Q');

    # Iterate through qualifiers

    for qualifier in qualifiers:
        if(qualifier.hasAttribute('end_x')):
            end_x= qualifier.getAttribute('end_x');
        elif(qualifier.hasAttribute('end_y')):
            end_y= qualifier.getAttribute('end_y');

    print start_x + ',' + start_y + ',' + end_x + ',' + end_y
```

The code above should do what you want. Something I noted is that originally the order was end_x then end_y then the order changed end_y end_x so in the sample correct format the end coordinates are flipped. So the output is

```
0.0,0.0,51.3,46.6,
49.9,49.0,51.0,46.6,
36.0,24.0,42.2,47.8,
51.0,46.6,34.1,49.3,
```

Hope this helps